# Moving to Maven

Tags: java, maven, build

I have inherited a java based, web based, 7 year old product with around 750K lines of code. As expected, given it's age, it is not on Maven based structure, . Maven is used to build and release the application. However, Maven is bastardized for the project and generally it is used to call Ant scripts.

I would like to move to Maven as in current setup on boarding any of the new(er) tools like Sonar, Hudson etc are a hassle.

I am polling the group to ask what should be a good strategy to make this change? Assuming I can somehow get the time and money to move the code around and get it mavenized, what is a efficient way to test that none of the functionality is broken due to mavenization. Needless to say, we cant rely on unit / integration testing as the code coverage is below 10%.

If I do a difference between the war created by the existing setup and the war created post mavenization, should the two wars be identical (in size and content)? If yes, is that a necessary and sufficient condition to guarantee that no functionality is broken?

Thanks.

Comment: Without sufficient code coverage, all bets are off.

Comment: Instead of moving to maven first get it on a good test automation. Money well spent.

Comment: I totally agree. But these are the facts of the industry that each professional in IT has to live with. I am sure all of you have worked on projects that do not have enough code coverage.

Comment: I agree @vivekv. I have mentioned that the code is around 750K to give people an idea that spending time and money on unit testing (although excellent advise from tech perspective) is not going to cut it with the management. There is no way we can get that much of code unit tested within a period of time that management will allow.

Comment: Be prepared to have real hard time if you are porting such a huge project to Maven. The biggest trouble you will have is to split it into multiple modules. Also, even after having a lot of tests, you would get into a lot of project structure and packaging issues and you will be far away from being able to run your tests.

Comment: @partha I dont get it.  Management will not pay for quality software but they will pay for a new build tool because... ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd probably recommend gradle, it seems way cooler than maven. Other than that, I think your plan of running the old and the new build and compare their result is a good idea.

Having said that, to be able to move on forward, you need to get some sort of integration-tests running, that is automatic click-through-testing with selenium or jweb unit.

So, I'd probably start by getting the old build up and running on jenkins/hudson/bamboo, then start writing click-through tests, and then start working with the build.

I'd also recommend [Working effectivly with legacy code](http://goo.gl/vOXD) as it will give you quite a few good tools for refactoring your code.

On testing if the different builds build the same stuff, I now do the following:

```
/opt/gradle/bin/gradle clean war && jar -tf build/libs/new.war  | sort > /tmp/gradle-war.txt && diff /tmp/ant-war.txt /tmp/gradle-war.txt
```

where /tmp/ant-war.txt is generated by

```
jar -tf old.war | sort | uniq > /tmp/ant-war.txt
```

This way I get a nice output of what's changed in the two builds.

Comment: Thanks. Have you used gradle though? It appeared (and please correct me if I am wrong) that most of the tools i.e. code coverage tools, Sonar, Jenkins etc have ready integration with Maven whereas Gradle does not really have that much of support yet. While I do not want to lag in the technology I do not really want to be on the bleeding edge either. But, good suggestion none the less. I will check out in more details. And thanks for the book.

Comment: Haven't used gradle in production, but I've been playing with it. Your point about maven being well integrated is a good point, I must admit. Why I'd like to use gradle is that it's less strict in project-layout than maven, and that I like programming in a programming-language and not in XML.

Answer (score 1):

The two wars likely won't be identical if you use Maven's standard folder structure when you switch over. You can alter the super pom to change the folders to match what you have, but in doing so you undermine one of the advantages of using Maven to begin with. I would stick to the standard.

As such, tests external to your codebase to validate functionality regardless of internal structure are desirable. Selenium is a good fit for this.

Comment: Absolutely. It is so fascinating to see so much being talked about code coverage and importance of testing etc and still a overwhelming amount of production code across industry failing so miserably in basic code sanity. It almost feels like, IT professionals (techies) need to have a more compelling united front, to push management to do things that are **required** and not spend money on just adding new features.